# php 7.4 install Imagick fails looking for undefined macro

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to install Imagick on my Debian 10 server running php 7.4 but I am getting a strange macro related error and I do not understand what that means.

pecl is installed

here is `sudo pecl install imagick`

```
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading imagick-3.4.4.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.4.4.tgz (253,434 bytes)
.....................................................done: 253,434 bytes
19 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
configure.ac:161: warning: LTOPTIONS_VERSION is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
build/libtool.m4:61: LT_INIT is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:99: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: LTSUGAR_VERSION is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
build/libtool.m4:61: LT_INIT is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:99: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: LTVERSION_VERSION is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
build/libtool.m4:61: LT_INIT is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:99: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: LTOBSOLETE_VERSION is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
build/libtool.m4:61: LT_INIT is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:99: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure:4702: error: possibly undefined macro: m4_ifval
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
configure:8297: error: possibly undefined macro: _LT_SET_OPTIONS
configure:8297: error: possibly undefined macro: LT_INIT
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe someone had published a buggy version of php7.4-dev which caused phpize failed to configure.

I happened to had the latest working version docker image with php7.4-dev and compared with latest php7.4-dev installed. Found `/usr/bin/phpize` has the following diff.

As a temporally solution, I think if you comment out `(cd "$aclocaldir" && cp $LIBTOOL_FILES "$builddir"/build)` line in `/usr/bin/phpize`, and change `FIELDS_BUILD` to `FILES_BUILD="php.m4 shtool libtool.m4 ax_check_compile_flag.m4 ax_gcc_func_attribute.m4 php_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4 pkg.m4 config.guess config.sub ltmain.sh Makefile.global"` it should work.

```
root@9dff9e6bd67b:/usr/bin# diff phpize-bad phpize-good
12c12,13
< FILES_BUILD="php.m4 shtool libtool.m4 ax_check_compile_flag.m4 ax_gcc_func_attribute.m4 php_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4 pkg.m4 config.guess config.sub ltmain.sh Makefile.global"
---
> aclocaldir="$prefix/share/aclocal"
> FILES_BUILD="php.m4 shtool ax_check_compile_flag.m4 ax_gcc_func_attribute.m4 php_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4 config.guess config.sub ltmain.sh Makefile.global"
13a15
> LIBTOOL_FILES="pkg.m4 libtool.m4 ltoptions.m4 ltsugar.m4 ltversion.m4 lt~obsolete.m4 glib-gettext.m4"
147a150
>   (cd "$aclocaldir" && cp $LIBTOOL_FILES "$builddir"/build)
```

Updates:

I believe the latest package already solved the issue, please apt-get update and apt-get install php7.4-dev again to solve the issue.

Comment: You beautiful soul :) Thank you ! I would like to ask how do you know about this bug and is there a tracker somewhere ?

Comment: @Sam, I happen to have a successful install several days ago so I had the docker image to be compared to, and I diff the phpize. I don't think this bug was reported yet, but I think it should be reported. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?dist=unstable;package=php7.4-dev

Comment: ha ok, and is this motif going to affect me for future updates ? Should I revert to original file at some point ? sorry Im not very informed on exactly what we did.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly today i had the same issue on Ubuntu though.
This used to work a while ago.

But for imagick you dont need to use PECL anymore, you can probably just use:

```
sudo apt install php-imagick
```

PHP imagick should be packaged for Debian: https://packages.debian.org/buster/php-imagick

Comment: I did that but still the same issue